# Format number based on conditional

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am new to python and struggling with a simple formating issue. I have a table with two columns - metrics and value. I am looking to format the value based on the name of the metric ( in the metrics column ). Can't seem to get it to work. I'd like the numbers to show as #,### and metrics with the name 'Pct ..." to be #.#%. The code runs ok but no changes are made. Also, some of the values may be nulls. Not sure how to handle that.

```
# format numbers and percentages
pct_options = ['Pct Conversion', 'Pct Gross Churn', 'Pct Net Churn']
for x in pct_options:
  if x in df['metrics']: 
    df.value.mul(100).astype('float64').astype(str).add('%')
  else:
    df.value.astype('float64')
```

Comment: Would you please post your desired result and a sample of your DataFrame?

Comment: You're not doing anything with the result of `astype()`.

Comment: It doesn't operate in place unless you use `copy=False`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can do it with [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html), try

```
#first convert your column to float if necessary note you need to reassign the column
df.value = df.value.astype('float64')
#then change only the rows with the right metrics with a mask created with isin
mask_pct = df.metrics.isin(pct_options)
df.loc[mask_pct, 'value'] = df.loc[mask_pct, 'value'].mul(100).astype(str).add('%')
```

EDIT here may be wahat you want:

```
#example df
df = pd.DataFrame({'metrics': ['val', 'Pct Conversion', 'Pct Gross Churn', 'ind', 'Pct Net Churn'], 'value': [12345.5432, 0.23245436, 0.4, 13, 0.000004]})
print (df)
           metrics         value
0              val  12345.543200
1   Pct Conversion      0.232454
2  Pct Gross Churn      0.400000
3              ind     13.000000
4    Pct Net Churn      0.000004
#change the formatting with np.where
pct_options = ['Pct Conversion', 'Pct Gross Churn', 'Pct Net Churn']
df.value = np.where(df.metrics.isin(pct_options), df.value.mul(100).map('{:.2f}%'.format), df.value.map('{:,.2f}'.format))
           metrics      value
0              val  12,345.54
1   Pct Conversion     23.25%
2  Pct Gross Churn     40.00%
3              ind      13.00
4    Pct Net Churn      0.00%
```

Comment: This seems to work for the metrics that need to be converted to percentages. But the others still look like xxxxx instead of x,xxx e.g 6000 instead of 6,000.  Also how can I limit the number of decimal places for the percentages to 2 digits ?